# Percorrer tabela com N linhas com FOR e encontrar valores específicos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como percorrer uma tabela com **N linhas** e encontrar os valores específicos de cada *DropDownList* ?

Exemplo da table abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei com o código abaixo, mas sem sucesso.

```
  function ValidarStatusGrid() {
        var temp, td;
        var table = $("tbPedidos");
        var status = $("#sclStatusGrid");
        temp = document.getElementById('tbPedidos').getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (var i = 0; i < temp.length + 1; i++) {
            td += temp[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Não dá pra colocar umas classes nesse dropdown? Aí não precisaria percorrer a tabela.

Comment: @bfavaretto acho que não pois, dependendo do status que estiver no dropdown ira desabilitar o mesmo ou realizar outra operação. E tudo tem que ser feito pelo lado do cliente

Comment: Bom, acho que a resposta abaixo resolve bem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra percorrer as linhas você pode fazer assim:

```
$('#tbPedidos> tbody  > tr').each(function() {
   // aqui tem a linha (tr)
   var linha = $(this);
});
```

Porém, se quer especificamente os selects na tabela, você pode fazer assim:

```
$('#tbPedidos select').each(function() {
    // aqui tem o valor da cada select
    var valor = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: $('#tbPedidos select') ta pegando todos os selects da tabela, se futuramente outra coluna também tiver selects vai misturar informações kk

Comment: Sim, isso atende o caso da pergunta, mas o melhor seria colocar uma classe ou name no `select` para poder selecionar corretamente, como @bfavaretto comentou acima

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz um foreach do jQuery nas `td` da tabela, e salvei peguei o valor usando `.val()` de cada elemento.

```js
  function ValidarStatusGrid() {
        var table = $("#tbPedidos");
        table.find('tbody tr').each(function() {
            var resultado = $(this).find('td select').find('option:selected').val();
            alert(resultado);
        });
    }
    $('#tbPedidos select').on('change', function () {
        ValidarStatusGrid();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbPedidos">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Pedido</td>
        <td>Selecione</td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>651981</td>
          <td><select><option value="valor selecionado 01">opção 01</option><option value="valor selecionado 02">opção 02</option></select></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```